# Pass a file as payload to AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, file-upload, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a file upload api that works fine. I want to create a resources at AWS API Gateway and link it up with my existing file upload api (http option).

I am unable to upload the file with AWS API Gateway even though I have configured the resource to pass through.

Each time I make a request to my resource at the API Gateway, I get a error that the file was not found as response from my existing API.

What is the proper way to create file upload resources that connects to an existing file upload API in AWS API Gateway?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by enabling 'Use HTTP Proxy integration' on my integration request setting.